# Can a charter school ask me to work more than 30 days on a 30 substitute permit?

Tags: education

I'm new to teaching and want to get my feet wet as a substitute teacher before committing to a credential program. There's a well-known charter school that would look amazing on my resume, but they're asking me to cover the same classroom for a 3 month period.

The problem is that I have a 30 day substitute permit, which states that I can work for the same teacher for no more than 30 days, consecutive or otherwise (http://www.ctc.ca.gov/credentials/leaflets/cl505p.pdf). What do I do? Is there really a penalty for me if anyone finds out?

Answer (score 2):

> What do I do?

Don't replace the same teacher for more than 30 days.

> Is there really a penalty for me if anyone finds out?

Yes, the commission has wide ranging powers to sanction a teacher for misconduct. Knowingly breaching the terms of your permit would prima facie be misconduct. See http://www.ctc.ca.gov/educator-discipline/FAQ.html